# C# SerialPort: ReadLine not working

Tags: c#, serial-port, thread-safety

i'm having issues reading input from a serial port in C#. The device, that is connected via usb, is a ELM327-Chip for reading the OBD-port of the car.

My Code consist of two threads: A Write- and a Read-Thread. It looks like the following:

```
static volatile SerialPort moPort;

...

moPort = new SerialPort("COM3");

moPort.BaudRate = 38400;
moPort.Parity = Parity.None;
moPort.DataBits = 8;
moPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
moPort.NewLine = "\r";
moPort.ReadTimeout = 5000;

moPort.Open();
```

Write-Thread:

```
for (; ; )
{
    foreach (string sPID in Car.getAvailablePIDs())
    {
        moPort.WriteLine("01 " + sPID);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

Read-Thread:

```
for (; ; )
{
    string sResult;
    try
    {
    sResult = moPort.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
    return;
    }
}
```

This way my program is working properly. The Input I get from the Device looks like the following:

```
41 0C 00 1C\r
41 1E 00\r
>NO DATA
```

The problem just occurs when I dont use the sleep function in the main-thread. The response I receive from the device then looks like the following:

```
41 0C
00 1C
\r41 1E
00\r
>NO
DATA
```

It doesn't seperate the strings anymore by '\r' but just sends ... chaos.

I have no idea what I should do or if there is anything wrong with my code. Has anyone suggestions?

MfG Kyle

Comment: Your reader and writer thread are not synchronized at all.  You can't call WriteLine() until ReadLine() completed.  Using Thread.Sleep() synchs by accident, not one you can ever count on.  Best to stop using threads, make it work correctly first.

Comment: Ah I thought i could use them independently from each other. Is there a way I can sync them when I dont't know, how many lines i will reveice from the device? It differs for every command I send.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: SerialPort implementation in C# sucks. There are many, many problems, i.e. works on some emulated ports but not on physical (none of the devices we tested). I recommend using http://serialportstream.codeplex.com/ I wanted to tell you this first because I wasted many tears, blood and hair fighting with many alogic behaviours of standard SerialPort class.

Now, regarding your code - the most important thing is to seperate the read-write logic completely. You can write as you like but please consider reading data as in my example below

```
port.DataReceived += port_DataReceived;
```

and the handler

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, RJCP.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {       
        SerialPortStream sp = (SerialPortStream)sender;

        if (sp.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            int bytes_rx = sp.Read(buffer, 0, BYTES_MAX);           

            if (datacollector != null)
                datacollector.InsertData(buffer, bytes_rx);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ///project specific code here...
    }
}
```