# C# serial port sometimes missing data

Tags: c#

Hi i have create a program in C# to receive a string of ASCII the string is an XML markup.

The computer i receive the data from i have no control over and does not accept a response it sends out data on the COM port about every 10 mins

The Console app i have collects and stores this data but it does not always work i would say about 50% of the time data is missing like a packet or byte was lost and the XML string wont read into XmlDocument

I have been trying for about a week now to make this more stable but this is my first time in C# and would like some help is there anyway to improve this.

CODE

```
  class SerialPortProgram : IDisposable
  {
    // Create the serial port with basic settings
    private SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1",
       115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

    string sBuffer = null;
    string filePath1 = @"C:\Data\data1.xml";
    string filePath2 = @"C:\Data\data2.xml";

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Instatiate this class
        new SerialPortProgram();

    }

    private SerialPortProgram() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started Data Monitoring:");

        //Attach a method to be called when there
        //is data waiting in the port's buffer
        port.ReadBufferSize = 20971520;
        port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Port_DataReceived);

        //Begin communications
        port.Open();

        //Enter an application loop to keep this thread alive
        Application.Run();

    }

    private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        sBuffer += sp.ReadExisting();

        if (sBuffer.Length > 26000) // check the file size
        {
            if (sBuffer.Substring(sBuffer.Length - 6) == "</xml>") // check for end of file
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found: Processing...");
                //Thread.Sleep(1000);
                ProcessXML();
                sBuffer = null;
                Console.WriteLine("Done!");
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                Console.WriteLine(now);
                Console.WriteLine("Monitoring...");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Still Receiving Data: " + sBuffer.Length);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Receiving Data: " + sBuffer.Length);
        }
    }
 private void ProcessXML()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            xmlDoc.LoadXml("<wrapper>" + sBuffer + "</wrapper>");
            int index = 0;
            XmlNodeList xnl = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("wrapper/xml");
            foreach (XmlNode node in xnl)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine(index.ToString());
                if (index == 0)// xml file 1
                {
                    using (XmlReader r = new XmlNodeReader(node))
                    {
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        ds.ReadXml(r);
                        ds.WriteXml(filePath1);
                        Console.WriteLine("NEW Data1");
                        ds.Dispose();
                        var db = new Database();
                        db.SaveMetersToDatabase(ds);
                    }
                }
                else if (index == 1)// xml file 2
                {
                    using (XmlReader r1 = new XmlNodeReader(node))
                    {
                        DataSet dst = new DataSet();
                        dst.ReadXml(r1);
                        dst.WriteXml(filePath2);
                        Console.WriteLine("NEW Data2");
                        dst.Dispose();
                    }
                }

                index++;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: in data");
            try
            {
                string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Data\log" + now + ".xml", "<wrapper>" + sBuffer + "</wrapper>");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to write to log");
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && port != null)
        {
            port.Dispose();
            port = null;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

  }
}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
  private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        sBuffer += sp.ReadExisting();

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            if (sBuffer.Length > 25000) // check the file size
            {
                if (sBuffer.Substring(sBuffer.Length - 6) == "</xml>") // check for end of file
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found: Processing...");
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        ProcessXML();
                        sBuffer = null;
                        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                        Console.WriteLine(now);
                        Console.WriteLine("Monitoring...");
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Still Receiving Data: " + sBuffer.Length);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Receiving Data: " + sBuffer.Length);
            }
        }).Start();
    }
```

UPDATE

still having this issue could it be possible that the sending computer sometimes does not send all the data or there is packet loss i have tried everything i have tried this new code below using Serial Port BaseStream BeginRead

```
  private SerialPortProgram() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started Data Monitoring:");

        //Attach a method to be called when there
        try
        {
            Port.BaudRate = 115200;
            Port.DataBits = 8;
            Port.Parity = Parity.None;
            Port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            Port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            Port.DtrEnable = true;
            Port.NewLine = Environment.NewLine;
            Port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 2048;
            Port.Open();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[35000];
            Action StartRead = null;
            StartRead = () => {
                Port.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, async (IAsyncResult ar) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int actualLength = Port.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);
                        byte[] received = new byte[actualLength];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, received, 0, actualLength);
                        await Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            sBuffer += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received);
                            CheckBuffer();
                        });
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(exc);
                    }
                    StartRead();
                }, null);
            };
            StartRead();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error accessing port." + ex);
            Port.Dispose();
            Application.Exit();
        }

        //Enter an application loop to keep this thread alive
        Application.Run();
    }

    private void CheckBuffer()
    {
        if (sBuffer != null && sBuffer.Length > 26000) // check the file size
        {
            if (sBuffer.Substring(sBuffer.Length - 6) == "</xml>") // check for end of file
            {
                new Thread(async () =>
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Found: Processing...");

                   await Task.Run(() => ProcessXML());

                   sBuffer = null;
                   Console.WriteLine("Done!");
                   DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                   Console.WriteLine(now);
                   Console.WriteLine("Monitoring...");
               }).Start();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Still Receiving Data: " + sBuffer.Length);
            }
        }
        else if (sBuffer != null && sBuffer.Length > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Receiving Data: " + sBuffer.Length);
        }

    }
```

Comment: what's the sleep for?  that's just asking to lose data

Comment: yeah ok i didnt think it would affect it it was there as it was saving the file a reopening it but no longer needed have removed

Comment: With communications, you want to minimise the amount of time in your callback else you will lose data.  I suggest you use a _circular buffer_ or similar technique and move your processing of said buffer to another _thread_

Comment: Please take a look at my anwer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33310396/c-sharp-serialport-readline-not-working/33311006#33311006 and tell if the problem persists while using the control mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Oh, and you should use much smaller buffer, receive all the data, put it on queue or sth and then analyze the data (when the data is present on your side). Consider one thread for receiving the data only so you won't experience any lags (remember - single responsibility) and another for parsing it. I've always separated it into two classes - Receiver, and Processor. I can show you sample implementation if you'd like

Comment: @Peuczyński Thanks for you help i am trying to make these changes i have moved processXML to another thread. can you please show an example?

Comment: I have tried a few different ways and have tried to add processXML() on a new thread I still have same issue can anyone provide an example?

Comment: Post your **updated** code

Comment: I do have to say using the updated code has reduced the problem i would say it works about 90% and fail 10% now so is a lot better

Comment: should i use something other then C# for serial port data?

Comment: @Anthony I will post an example for you as soon as I will remove the sensitive data from the code

Comment: i have made update to my code as shown above but still have the issues of missing bytes sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my implementation.
You should get the general idea

First - get the data from the connection

```
internal class SerialListener : Listener
{
    private SerialPort sp;
    private ConnectionInfo _connection;
    private Timer _listenerTimer;
    private bool should_exit = false;
    private bool busy = false;
    ConcurrentQueue<byte> fifo_peekonly = null;
    BlockingCollection<byte> fifo_queue = null;

    public SerialListener(ConnectionInfo connection)
        : base(connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
        InitSerialConnection();
    }

    private void InitSerialConnection()
    {
        sp = new SerialPort(_connection.ifname_ip);
        sp.BaudRate = _connection.baudrate_port;
        sp.Parity = _connection.parity;
        sp.DataBits = _connection.charactersize;
        sp.StopBits = _connection.stopbits;
        sp.Handshake = _connection.flowcontrol;
        sp.DtrEnable = true;
        sp.ReadTimeout = 100;
        sp.Open();
        fifo_peekonly = new ConcurrentQueue<byte>();
        fifo_queue = new BlockingCollection<byte>(fifo_peekonly);
        sp.DataReceived += (sender, e) => 
        { 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
            if (!sp.IsOpen)
            {
                throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Serial port is closed.");
            }
            sp.Read(buffer,0,sp.BytesToRead);
            foreach (var b in buffer)
                fifo_queue.Add(b);
        };
    }

    public override byte GetByteFromDevice()
    {
        byte b;
        b = fifo_queue.Take();
        return b;
    }

    public override byte PeekByteFromDevice ()
    {
        byte b;
        bool peeked = false;
        do {
            peeked = fifo_peekonly.TryPeek(out b);
            if (!peeked)
                Thread.Sleep(100);
        } while (!peeked);
        return b;
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        base.Close();
        sp.DiscardInBuffer();
        sp.DiscardOutBuffer();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        sp.Close();
    }
}
```

Then implement another class that will call the `GetByteFromDevice` method. Unfortunatelly the code is too specific to bo posted here as it would be only confusing for you.

So - separate the logic, and push all the bytes in real time, and in a separate thread (some loop, timer etc.) get the bytes read previously and then analyze them.

Also the method you are using for xml detection is not optimal in my opinion. I have implemented detecting the start and end sequence in the stream. Let me know if you'd like to look at the code

Comment: thanks for you help but i was not successful using some of this code in my current program

Comment: I have accepted this answer I have now got this code working after some changes and it have fix my problem. If you have code for xml detection that would good to see

Comment: I don't have such code but I can tell you how I'd do it. You have all the characters on the queue you can peek the queue to monitor the xml start and then trace the opening vs closing tags. Look for similar questions like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891223/better-way-to-detect-xml.

Comment: Thanks for your help I had tried a lot of different code for serial port read over the past month this was the only code I have got to work fast and flawless every time

Comment: IMO the only thing that could be not optimal in your solution is that you had is that you had big buffer instead of discarding what you didn't need

Comment: Let me know if I can be of more help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not exactly the desired answer,

but I am sharing the solution to the data evasion that I encountered. Actually, I was not escaping data. In the SerialPort default settings, `ReadBufferSize` is set to 4096. When data packet was over 4096 Bytes it was ignoring other data and was not displayed in `DataReceived`.

Setting the `ReadBufferSize` to a value that suited me fixed the issue.